# RxJS/ReactiveX Proper modules communication

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, reactivex, reactive-extensions-js

I'm pretty new to Reactive Programming but already in love. However it is still hard to switch my brain to it. I'm trying to follow all recommendations as "Avoid using subjects" and "Avoid impure functions" and of course "Avoid imperative code."

What I'm finding hard to achieve is simple cross modules communications where one module can register "action"/observable and the other could subscribe and react to it. A simple message bus will probably work but this will enforce the usage of Subjects and imperative code style which I'm trying to avoid.

So here is a simple starting point I'm playing with:

```
    // some sandbox
class Api {
  constructor() {
    this.actions = {};
  }

  registerAction(actionName, action) {
    // I guess this part will have to be changed
    this.actions[actionName] = action.publishReplay(10).refCount();
    //this.actions[actionName].connect();
  }

  getAction(actionName) {
    return this.actions[actionName];
  }
}

const api = new Api();

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
// module 1
let myAction = Rx.Observable.create((obs) => {
  console.log("EXECUTING");
  obs.next("42 " + Date.now());
  obs.complete();
});

api.registerAction("myAction", myAction);

let myTrigger = Rx.Observable.interval(1000).take(2);

let executedAction = myTrigger
.flatMap(x => api.getAction("myAction"))
.subscribe(
  (x) => { console.log(`executed action: ${x}`); },
  (e) => {}, 
  () => { console.log("completed");});

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
// module 2
api.getAction("myAction")
  .subscribe(
  (x) => { console.log(`SECOND executed action: ${x}`); },
  (e) => {}, 
  () => { console.log("SECOND completed");});
```

So currently at the moment the second module subscribes it "triggers" the "myAction" Observable. And in a real life scenario that could be an ajax call. Is there any way to make all subscribers delay/wait until "myAction" is called properly from module1? And again - its easy to do it using subjects but I'm trying to do it following recommended practices.

Comment: What do you mean by *"myAction" is called properly from module1*? You mean until it completes or what?

Comment: Yes. complete will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is a much simpler solution than the one I thought. With simply using 2 observables. Similar effect could be achieved with schedulers and subscribeOn.

```
    // some sandbox
class Action {
  constructor(name, observable) {
    this.name = name;
    this.observable = observable;
    this.replay = new Rx.ReplaySubject(10);
  }
}

function actionFactory(action, param) {

  return Rx.Observable.create(obs => {
    action.observable
    .subscribe(x => {
        obs.next(x);
        action.replay.next(x);
    }, (e) => {}, () => obs.complete);
  }); 
}

class Api {
  constructor() {
    this.actions = {};
  }

  registerAction(actionName, action) {
    let generatedAction = new Action(actionName, action);

    this.actions[actionName] = generatedAction;

    return actionFactory.bind(null, generatedAction);
  }

  getAction(actionName) {
    return this.actions[actionName].replay;
  }
}

const api = new Api();

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
// module 1
let myAction = Rx.Observable.create((obs) => {
  obs.next("42 " + Date.now());
  obs.complete();
});

let myRegisteredAction$ = api.registerAction("myAction", myAction);

let myTrigger = Rx.Observable.interval(1000).take(1).delay(1000);

let executedAction = myTrigger
.map(x => { return { someValue: x} })
.concatMap(x => myRegisteredAction$(x))
.subscribe(
  (x) => { console.log(`MAIN: ${x}`); },
  (e) => { console.log("error", e)}, 
  () => { console.log("MAIN: completed");});


// -------------------------------------------------------------------
// module 2
 var sub = api.getAction("myAction")
  .subscribe(
  (x) => { console.log(`SECOND: ${x}`); },
  (e) => {console.log("error : " + e)}, 
  () => { console.log("SECOND: completed");});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to make the sure that, if you call the api.getAction, you want next values in that observable to wait till the call to the getAction completes. Before handling other values.

This is something you can achieve quite easily using the concatMap. ConcatMap will take a function that returns an observable (in your case the call to the getAction). ConcatMap will wait to start handling the next value, until the observable returned in the function completes.

So if you change your code like this, it should work (if I understood correctly).

```
let executedAction = myTrigger
.concatMap(x => api.getAction("myAction"))
.subscribe(
  (x) => { console.log(`executed action: ${x}`); },
  (e) => {}, 
  () => { console.log("completed");});
```

If myTrigger has a new value, it will not be handled until the observable returned from api.getAction completes.

Comment: Thanks. This is improvement I was considering. However my main problem is that the subscribtion from module2 triggers the emit before the one from module1. So I guess I need some kind of delay until emited and then subscribe? But as far as I'm going into the documentation the delay could be only time (using rxjs5)

Comment: So you want the call from module 1 to complete before handling the one from module2. But the question is, if its an AJAX call, do you want the call to be executed twice or do you want the call from the second module to trigger a second request

Comment: I just want the subscribe from module2 to only "listen" without "trigger" the request

Comment: As I dig deeper I think the best way to achieve this is with scheduler? custom one. But can't figure out if you can create custom schedulers yet.